# Easier way to make BackBlaze pause/resume updating

Tags: macos, mac, backup

I use BackBlaze for my online backups, and i love it except for one small feature they refuse to add (to the Mac client anyway).  Occasionally it will be backing up my data when i don't want it to (doing something online, watching a Netflix streaming movie on my Roku, etc) and it hogs the network.  So I have to pause the backup, that sets a 2 hour delay on it which is usually sufficient.

My issue is that the "pause backup" and "resume backup" options are not in the menubar software they provide.  I have to open the BackBlaze system preferences, wait for it to load, and hit the pause button there.

I'd love to have a way to make this a lot easier and quicker.  Possibly some terminal commands that I could run from somewhere? There's obviously simple commands to do this, but they don't provide a simple way to access them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pause appears in the menubar if you option click it.

Comment: Awesome, I did not realize that was possible - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you use Alfred, try this workflow I created to quickly pause and start backups: [Alfred-Backblaze](http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/4365-backblaze-pause-and-sync-workflow/). It's basically just a pretty wrapper around executing '/Library/Backblaze.bzpkg/bztransmit -pausebackup' and '/Library/Backblaze.bzpkg/bztransmit -completesync' respectively.